# Showing Null fields in JqGrid

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have my grid set up but any fields in my data that are NULL on my server are showing up as blanks in the grid.

Is there any way to show them as NULL inside the grid instead of just blank cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JCooper normally jqgrid returns the data same as from the server. Check if you used any conversion method.  if you still want to replace the value i guess you can use [CustomFormatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter).

Answer (score 0):

If the data that you are returning from the server contains null values..they are displayed as empty cells in jqgrid by default..there is no need to do any extra processing .